# What caused bin/rails: compared with non class/module (TypeError)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was in the process of Rails upgrade from Rails 5.0.6 to 5.1.7.
I ran this command

```
bundle update composite_primary_keys rails activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter state_machines-activerecord
```

and then now running `rails c` gives this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
bin/rails: compared with non class/module (TypeError)
```

I have no idea how to start fixing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
bin/rails: compared with non class/module (TypeError)
```

Any idea what caused this error?

Comment: Is that a complete output? No trace?

Comment: @katafrakt Yes, no trace

Comment: Can you post content of `bin/rails` then? Maybe it's there.

Comment: @katafrakt Thank you for looking into this, I think the `bin/rails` display the same output (besides the normal 300 port stuff) as the `rails c`. I solved this problem by upgrading other gems to later version using ` bundle update`. I will add that as an answer to this question and choose that as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, running `bundle update` solve this problem and `rails c` start running correctly. I suspect the following gem upgrade might be the solution to this issue:

From:

```
state_machines-activerecord (0.4.1)
  activerecord (>= 4.1, < 5.2)
  state_machines-activemodel (>= 0.3.0)
```

To:

```
state_machines-activerecord (0.6.0)
  activerecord (>= 4.1)
  state_machines-activemodel (>= 0.5.0)
```